# Comparing 2 columns in same dataframe and display unmatch records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare 2 columns values from same dataframe and display rows with unmatch values. However, there are str value type in column Profit.

```
diff = c.loc[~(c['Profit'] == c['Profit1'])]
```

Comment: what is the problem here? we have no clue what the data looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force data types when comparing the two columns to make sure the columns are the same.

```
diff = c[c['Profit'].astype(int,errors='ignore') != c['Profit1'].astype(int,errors='ignore')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, I create a sample df with  strings and ints

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Profit':['A',2,'C','B','C','A','B','A',3],'Profit1':['B',2,'B','D','D','A','B','D',4]})
```

Now we can get the rows with unmatched values with

```
df[df["Profit"]!= df["Profit1"]]
```